# Calculating vowel to word length ratio in a list of words

Tags: python

Here is the code for my function:

```
def calcVowelProportion(wordList):
    """
    Calculates the proportion of vowels in each word in wordList.
    """

    VOWELS = 'aeiou'
    ratios = []

    for word in wordList:
        numVowels = 0
        for char in word:
            if char in VOWELS:
                numVowels += 1
        ratios.append(numVowels/float(len(word)))
```

Right now, I'm working with a list of over 87,000 words and this algorithm is obviously extremely slow.

Is there a better way to do this?

EDIT:

I tested the algorithms @ExP provided with the following class:

```
    import time

    class vowelProportions(object):
        """
        A series of methods that all calculate the vowel/word length ratio
        in a list of words.
        """

        WORDLIST_FILENAME = "words_short.txt"

        def __init__(self):
            self.wordList = self.buildWordList()
            print "Original: " + str(self.calcMeanTime(10000, self.cvpOriginal, self.wordList))
            print "Generator: " + str(self.calcMeanTime(10000, self.cvpGenerator, self.wordList))
            print "Count: " + str(self.calcMeanTime(10000, self.cvpCount, self.wordList))
            print "Translate: " + str(self.calcMeanTime(10000, self.cvpTranslate, self.wordList))

        def buildWordList(self):
            inFile = open(self.WORDLIST_FILENAME, 'r', 0)
            wordList = []
            for line in inFile:
                wordList.append(line.strip().lower())
            return wordList

        def cvpOriginal(self, wordList):
            """ My original, slow algorithm"""
            VOWELS = 'aeiou'
            ratios = []

            for word in wordList:
                numVowels = 0
                for char in word:
                    if char in VOWELS:
                        numVowels += 1
                ratios.append(numVowels/float(len(word)))

            return ratios

        def cvpGenerator(self, wordList):
            """ Using a generator expression """
            return [sum(char in 'aeiou' for char in word)/float(len(word)) for word in wordList]

        def cvpCount(self, wordList):
            """ Using str.count() """
            return [sum(word.count(char) for char in 'aeiou')/float(len(word)) for word in wordList]

        def cvpTranslate(self, wordList):
            """ Using str.translate() """
            return [len(word.translate(None, 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstxyz'))/float(len(word)) for word in wordList]

        def timeFunc(self, func, *args):
            start = time.clock()
            func(*args)
            return time.clock() - start

        def calcMeanTime(self, numTrials, func, *args):
            times = [self.timeFunc(func, *args) for x in range(numTrials)]
            return sum(times)/len(times)
```

The output was (for a list of 200 words):

```
Original: 0.0005613667
Generator: 0.0008402738
Count: 0.0012531976
Translate: 0.0003343548
```

Surprisingly, Generator and Count were even slower than the original (please let me know if my implementation was incorrect).

I would like to test @John's solution, but don't know anything about trees.

Comment: I guess it should be worth noting that you should `(1) VOWELS = 'aeiouAEIOU'` or `(2) change first for to for word.lower() in wordList:`

Comment: unless the list contains words which are lowercase already

Comment: @ryrich The list I'm working with contains only lowercase words, but thank you - I forgot to mention that.

Comment: A couple of small optimisations to try: 1. Try creating the `ratios` list in a single step e.g. `ratios = [None] * len(wordList)`.  Appending will likely require the backing array to be resized which is slow.  2. Try turning `VOWELS` into a set.  In my experience testing whether a value is in a set is significantly faster than for a list at least.  You'll need to test this to confirm of course.

Answer (score 4):

You should optimize the innermost loop.

I'm pretty sure there are several alternative approaches. Here is what I can come up with right now. I'm not sure how they will compare in speed (with respect to each other and to your solution).

- Using a generator expression:

  ```
  numVowels = sum(x in 'aeiou' for x in word)
  ```
- Using `str.count()`:

  ```
  numVowels = sum(word.count(x) for x in 'aeiou')
  ```
- Using `str.translate()` (assuming there are no capital letters or special symbols):

  ```
  numVowels = len(word.translate(None, 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstxyz'))
  ```

With all of these, you can even write the whole function in a single line without `list.append()`.

I would be curious to know which turns out to be the fastest.

Comment: `numVowels` can be reduced to : `sum(x in vowels for x in word)`, as this requires only a single iteration of the word, while`str.count` will result in 5 iterations.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary good point, I eddited my answer to reflect your first comment.

Comment: `len(x for x in word if x in 'aeiou')` won't work -- genexps don't have length.  You'd need to `len` a listcomp or `sum(1 for..)` etc. or something.

Comment: @DSM Thanks, I didn't pay attention to that.

Comment: Surprisingly, `translate` is about three times faster than the first generator expression. The second one is the slowest.

Answer (score 4):

Since you're just concerned with the ratio of vowels to letters in each word, you could first replace all of the vowels with `a`.  Now you can try a couple of things that might be faster:

- You're testing for one letter instead of five at each step.  That's bound to be faster.
- You might be able to sort the whole list and search for the points where you go from vowel (now represented categorically as `a`) to non-vowel.  This is a tree structure.  The number of letters in the word is the level of the tree.  The number of vowels is the number of left branches.

Comment: replacing letters with other letters does cost time... Same with sorting. It would be nice to actually time all these ideas.

Comment: That's true.  I'd expect that built-in search/replace would be pretty efficient, and it would reduce the loop execution by 80%.  (I'm not in a position to verify now, unfortunately.)

Comment: I think this answer is going to be the most fruitful, but do the letter replacement outside python. `cat wordlist | tr aeiou a | tr qwrtpsdfghjklzxcvbnm b > new_wordlist` and then process that.

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression to match the list of vowels and count the number of matches.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'supercalifragilisticexpialidocious'
>>> len(re.findall('[aeiou]', s))
16
```

Comment: Regular expressions are most likely an overkill. I don't think the `re` matching engine is fast enough to compete even with his initial solution.

Comment: @ExP, I'm thinking the `re` code is in highly optimized C. It's certainly worth a shot. I might try to benchmark it if I get a few seconds.

Comment: @MarkRansom: The compiled regex is only a little slower than a generator expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
for word in wordlist:
    numVowels = 0
    for letter in VOWELS:
        numVowels += word.count(letter)
    ratios.append(numVowels/float(len(word)))
```

less decision making, should mean less time, also uses built in things, which i believe work faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
import timeit

words = 'This is a test string'

def vowelProportions(words):
    counts, vowels = {}, 'aeiou'
    wordLst = words.lower().split()
    for word in wordLst:
        counts[word] = float(sum(word.count(v) for v in vowels)) / len(word)
    return counts

def f():
    return vowelProportions(words)

print timeit.timeit(stmt = f, number = 17400) # 5 (len of words) * 17400 = 87,000
# 0.838676
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to calculate it with one command line on Linux:-

`cat wordlist.txt | tr -d aeiouAEIOU | paste - wordlist.txt | gawk  '{ FS="\t"; RATIO = length($1)/ length($2); print $2, RATIO }'`

Output:

```
aa 0
ab 0.5
abs 0.666667
```

Note: Each line in `wordlist.txt` contains a word. Empty lines will produce divide by zero error

Comment: With Python, it is more complex, pipe it to: ` |  python -c "import sys; tmp = lambda x: sys.stdout.write(x.split('\t')[1] + str( float(len(x.split('\t')[0]))/float(len(x.split('\t')[1])-1) ) + '\n'); map(tmp, sys.stdin);"